# ListView itemId is always 0

Tags: java, android, listview, android-cursoradapter

The value returned by id parameter of `setOnItemClickListener` is always **0(zero)** no matter which position i click on the value returned is always **0**

but the value of position of correct and i have also tried `adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i)` and still the value on clicking each item in list is **zero**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

ListView onlineList;
FloatingActionButton onlineListFab;
private static final int mLoaderId  = 1;
ListAdapter listAdapter;

public ListFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    initilize(v);
    return v;
}

private void initilize(View v) {
    onlineList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.onlineList);
    onlineListFab = (FloatingActionButton)v.findViewById(R.id.onlineListFab);
    onlineListFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),AddItem.class));
        }
    });
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),null);
    onlineList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    onlineList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent details = new Intent(getActivity(),AddItem.class);
            details.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(TableName.mContentUri,String.valueOf(l)));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),l+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //startActivity(details);
        }
    });
    loadItems();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id){
        case mLoaderId:
            return new CursorLoader(getContext(), TableName.mContentUri,null,null,null,null);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    listAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    listAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

private void loadItems() {
    if (getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(mLoaderId) == null) {
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(mLoaderId, null, this).forceLoad();
    } else {
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(mLoaderId, null, this).forceLoad();
    }
}
}
```

AdapterCode :

```
public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter{


public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView name,price;
    name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
    name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableName.table1.mName)));
    price.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableName.table1.mPrice))));
}
}
```

Comment: because your ContentProvider returns 0 for _id column... or you override getItemId in your adapter implementation ... but it's just a blind guess as you didn't provide most important code ...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing new `ListAdapter(getActivity(),null);` which is a custom class seeing as you can't do that with an interface. Have you updated the default getItemId method? I'd gamble not.

Off the top of my head, your adapter will need an implementation similar to:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    long result = 0;
    if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        Log.d("SO", DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRowToString(mCursor);
        result = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(TableName.table1.mId));
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you can't resolve the problem take a look at the data itself in your cursors using [DatabaseUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html)

Comment: Yes you're extending Cursor adapter as I expected, so this should work, just add that method into ListAdapter (it's bad idea to name a concrete class the same as an interface btw. Your IDE should warn you)

Comment: Nope it didn't solve the error still the value returned is zero

Comment: Did you make sure TableName.table1.mId is the right column and also Log out what getLong returns, and whether moveToPosition is successful?

Comment: Done still zero

Comment: Well if it is definitely calling getLong (ie moveToPosition is successful) and that is returning 0, then the problem is in the data. try the log I just added above and see what you have